# Trigger to write last inserted date based on other table inserts

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers

I have 48 tables in which data is inserted continuously. So I want to have one table which shows the last inserted date for each table.
So I want such table.

[image]

So whenever the data inserted the trigger should update this table with appropriate tables name.

I am confused about the algorithm.

Should I write a trigger that writes the last insert date for each table like `update table set = now() where tables = 'table_1'`,
or is there any approach that handles this only with one trigger function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one trigger function for all tables. Use `TG_TABLE_NAME` [trigger function special variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) in the function. Here is an example.

```sql
create or replace function register_time_tf()
returns trigger language plpgsql as
$$
begin
  update the_table set last_inserted = now() where tables = TG_TABLE_NAME;
  return null;
end;
$$;
```

Then set this function as an AFTER INSERT trigger on all 48 tables.